Intuition behind the identity $\overline{\phi^*(V(\mathfrak b))}=V(\mathfrak b^c)$
All rings in this question will be commutative, and ring homomorphisms are required to send $1$ to $1$. Suppose $\phi:A\to B$ is a ring homomorphism, $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $Y=\operatorname{Spec} B$. The map $\phi$ induces a continuous map $\phi^*:Y\to X$ given by sending each prime ideal in $B$ to its contraction in $A$. In Atiyah and Macdonald, there is an exercise asking for a proof of the identity $\overline{\phi^*(V(\mathfrak b))}=V(\mathfrak b^c)$ for all ideals $\mathfrak b$ in $B$. Is there an intuition behind why the identity holds? It seems that this theorem has some geometric content to it, but none of the proofs I have seen feel particularly geometric. I am also curious if there is an analogue of the identity in classical algebraic geometry, where $V(\mathfrak a)$ denotes the vanishing locus of $\mathfrak a$, rather than the set of prime ideals including $\mathfrak a$.

the vanishing set is the set of prime ideals including a, at least that is the definition I know. However, may I ask what you mean by $\mathfrak{b}^c$? I would read it at the moment as, if you see the two spaces as spaces, then the vanishing set should be a distinguished closed set and the pullback of this closed set along $\phi$ after closure being again a distinguished closed set corresponding to the ideal $\mathfrak{b}$ after contraction along $\phi$.

@Felix: By $\mathfrak b^c$ I mean the contraction of $\mathfrak b$, i.e. $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak b)$. When I said "vanishing locus" of $\mathfrak a$, I was talking about the case where $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal of $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ for some algebraically closed field $K$, in which case $V(\mathfrak a)$ is classically defined to be ${x\in K^n\mid\text{$p(x)=0$ for all $p\in\mathfrak a$}}$. Apologies if this wasn't clear.

We'll play a little fast and loose with what "vanishing" means here, but you can make all of this work no matter what definition of "vanishing" you pick, and you did say that you were looking for intuition anyways.
Suppose $f$ is a function on $X$. The function $f$ vanishes on $\phi^*(V(\mathfrak{b}))$ if and only if the pullback of $f$ vanishes on $V(\mathfrak{b})$. As the map $A\to B$ is given by pullback and the functions vanishing on $V(\mathfrak{b})$ are exactly $\mathfrak{b}$, this means that $f$ vanishing on $\phi^*(V(\mathfrak{b}))$ is equivalent to the image of $f$ in $B$ lying in $\mathfrak{b}$, or $f\in\mathfrak{b}^c$. So the functions vanishing on $\phi^*(V(\mathfrak{b}))$ are exactly $\mathfrak{b}^c$. As $V(I(S))=\overline{S}$, this gives that $\overline{\phi^*(V(\mathfrak{b}))}= V(\mathfrak{b}^c)$ and we're done.

Here is a proof that I find a little more intelligible than the other ones that I have read, although I am still not completely happy with it.
Let $\phi:A\to B$, $X$, $Y$, and $\mathfrak b\subseteq B$ be as in the question. We first note that $\phi^*(V(\mathfrak b))=\phi^*(V(\sqrt{\mathfrak b}))$, since if $q\in\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}\Spec B$, then $q\supseteq\mathfrak b$ if and only if $q\supseteq\sqrt{\mathfrak b}$. Moreover, $V((\sqrt{\mathfrak b})^c)=V(\sqrt{\mathfrak b^c})=V(\mathfrak b^c)$. Thus, to prove the assertion that $\overline{\phi^*(V(\mathfrak b))}=V(\mathfrak b^c)$ for all ideals $\mathfrak b\subseteq B$, it suffices to consider the case where $\mathfrak b$ is a radical ideal.
The inclusion $\phi^*(V(\mathfrak b))\subseteq V(\mathfrak b^c)$ is trivial, and since $V(\mathfrak b^c)$ is closed, it follows that $\overline{\phi^*(V(\mathfrak b))}\subseteq V(\mathfrak b^c)$. The inclusion $V(\mathfrak b^c)\subseteq\overline{\phi^*(V(\mathfrak b))}$ is less obvious, but here is my best attempt at explaining it. Since $\overline{\phi^*(V(\mathfrak b))}$ is closed, there is an ideal $\mathfrak a\subseteq A$ such that $\overline{\phi^*(V(\mathfrak b))}=V(\mathfrak a)$. Thus, $\phi^*(V(\mathfrak b))\subseteq V(\mathfrak a)$; concretely, this means that if $q\in\Spec B$ and $q\supseteq \mathfrak b$, then $q^c\supseteq\mathfrak a$. Since $\mathfrak b$ is a radical ideal, it is the intersection of the family of prime ideals $\{q_i\}$ which include it. Thus, $q_i^c\supseteq\mathfrak a$ for all $i$, so $\bigcap_{i} q_i^c\supseteq\mathfrak a$. Noting that
$$
\bigcap_iq_i^c=\bigcap_i\phi^{-1}(q_i)=\phi^{-1}\left(\bigcap_iq_i\right)=\mathfrak b^c \, ,
$$
we see that $\mathfrak a\subseteq\mathfrak b^c$, hence $V(\mathfrak a)=\overline{\phi^*(V(\mathfrak b))}\supseteq V(\mathfrak b^c)$.
